# Android Studio emulator is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

i´ve searched about an awnser for this problem, tried many things, but still it doesn't Work.
I'm using a win7 64-bit version.
I've set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable and... nothing.
With the path: `C:\Users\Nuno\Favorites\.android\avd`

The error is this:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find PhoneTest.ini file in $HOME\.android\avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working now!

How did i solved?
I copied the AVM's i created from c:\user\favorites.android\avd and pasted them at c:\user.android\avd.

Tbh i don't know why this happened but when i installed Android studio it created the first directory to put the avd's, while the HOME variable points to the second directory.

After that i had a second problem, it said it couldn't create the temp file... I just had to execute Android studio with administrative privileges.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It could help, but I did not understand: what did you exactly do?

Comment: The files had been installed in a different folder to the one expected. search 'avd' and check if you have multiple of these folders on your machine. You can then copy from one to the other.

Answer (score 4):

Im glad you have solved the problem.
This is the ubuntu version of your problem.
[This](http://kalpa-gunarathna.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-emulator-not-starting-on-ubuntu.html) explains why you need to admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks, this is clearly admin privilage issue. In my windows, I've started Android Studio as administrator to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue when installed and configured android studio on ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit).

After installation android studio successfully, when I run my app, I faced below issue:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: PANIC: HOME is defined but
>   could not find Nexus_5_API_21.ini file in $HOME/.android/avd (Note:
>   avd is searched in the order of
>   $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and
>   $HOME/.android/avd)

I discovered reason of issue and find solution of the same. Reason was that I had downloaded android_studio at home directory (path:/home/ubuntu/android_studio). When I started studio (by using command: $sudo sh /home/ubuntu/android_studio/bin/studio.sh), which is actually installed at path /root/, it is trying to access "root" user files at path /root/.android/avd

Ready to use solution is:
Use command with root user ie

`#sh /home/ubuntu/android_studio/bin/studio.sh`

in place of of

`$sudo sh /home/ubuntu/android_studio/bin/studio.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Add environment variables `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` as your emulator really in(show in capture below). avd manager create emulator in maybe in another directory(default C:\Users[User Name].android\avd on Windows).
As message show in tips, `avd` will search `xxxx/.android/avd`. So you setting environment variables above can solve the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQt8i.png)

Answer (score 0):

When AS was updated in Parallels and HAXM was installed after disabling Hyper-V, for me, the new avds somehow found their way into the Mac's .android folder?  I previously installed AS on the Mac but wanted to separate Xcode and AS, so I used Windows for AS and uninstalled it on the Mac.  When I opened AS from the dock, it was as if it was a fresh install and I didn't import settings...

Solution was to grab all my old emulators (folders and .ini files) and pasted them into the Window's .android/avd folder.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with me by setting the variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME and path D: \ ANDROID_SDK in S.O Windowns 7 Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I might not be answering your question but I strongly encourage you to switch for a new Android Emulator. Works prietty good for me:

[Genymotion Home Page](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment asking if they have the most recent version. This doesn't answer the question to solve the issue he is having.