# Can't launch AVD in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Actually , i installed my Android Studio on D partition instead of C as i don't have enough space on it , and when i tried to launch my emulator it gave me that error. I know it's a common problem so i searched about it, i only found that link but i didn't understand the solution : [Android Studio emulator is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014116/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working)

so how can i fix it ?

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find Galaxy_Nexus_API_18.ini file in $HOME\.android\avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\.android\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled over the same error.

(Assuming you are using Windows)

You have to set the environment variables `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`.

`ANDROID_AVD_HOME` should be `C:\Users\[Username]\.android\avd`

`ANDROID_SDK_HOME` should be `C:\Users\[Username]\`

And copy-paste the contents from your [My documents].android - folder to

```
C:\Users\[Username]\.android
```

Then start the SDK Manager again.

Image: [Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpihn.png)